# How to access a desired part of matrix from a text file.?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have created a matrix A and stored it in a file named MatrixA.txt using the below command

```
dlmwrite('MatrixA.txt',A);
```

now when i use 
    B=csvread('MatrixA.txt',r,c);

where r and c are the desired rows and desired cols of the matrix i cant get it because it takes the last part of the matrix.. 
for Ex... If i have 
    A=[1  2  3  4;
       5  6  7  8;
       9 10 11 12;
      13 14 15 16]

i want to have 
    B=[1 2;
       5 6]

But when i use 
    B=csvread('MatrixA.txt',2,2)

It gives 
    B=[11 12;
       15 16]

Please help guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
B=csvread('MatrixA.txt',0,0,[0 0 1 1])
```

In the call to `csvread` you have to specify:

- the starting `row` and `column` (which are `0-based`)
- the range of the data you want to read: `[R1 C1 R2 C2]` where (R1,C1) is the upper-left corner of the data to be read and (R2,C2) is the lower-right corner

Moreover you can read the whole matrix (for further usage) and then access to the sub-matrix you need:

```
B=csvread('MatrixA.txt')
start_row=1;
end_row=2;
start_column=1;
end_column=2;

B1=B(start_row:end_row,start_column:end_column)
```

Also, you can specify a step:

```
B=csvread('MatrixA.txt')
start_row=1;
end_row=4;
row_step=2;
start_column=1;
end_column=4;
column_step=2;

B2=B([start_row:row_step:end_row],[start_column:column_step:end_column])
```

As an alternative, you can use `dlmread`:

```
B=dlmread('MatrixA.txt',',',[0 0 1 1])
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. :)

Comment: You're welcome, happy I've been of use to you. To close the question and let the community know your problem has been fixed, you might want to mark the answer as "accepted".